# Sonarlint option is not showing in the eclipse for checking the particular Java file

Tags: eclipse, sonarlint, sonarlint-eclipse

Recently I have installed sonar lint into the eclipse. I have facing the below problem. Can you please someone suggests and guide me what is wrong from my side.

Problem:

SolarList is successfully installed at the first place. I do the right click on my project then I can see the option Sonar lint to validate my code but I have right clicked my single java file to check only the particular file at that the sonar lint option is not showing.

Attached below screenshot

[image]

[image]

Comment: The file icon shows an outline `J` which means the Java file is not in a source folder (not on the _Java Build Path_) and will therefore not compiled. I guess, Sonarlint requires the compiled `.class` files or at least the `.java` files on the _Java Build Path_ to work.

Comment: Yeah, try the same on the package tree.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz- Thanks.Will try it out

Comment: convert your project to maven project and see it will work